# How do I use ipstack and ajax to get the country code of a user?

Tags: jquery, ajax, geolocation

I am using https://ipstack.com to geolocate users so I can show a popup based on country. I am trying to grab the country code, but so far all I get is undefined.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=MY_API_KEY&fields=country_code',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json){
            alert(json.country_code);
        }
    });
```

I expect this to return the country code "US" since I'm in the US, but it just returns "undefined" instead.

Comment: what's the output if you `console.log(json)`?

Comment: {success: false, error: {…}}
error: {code: 105, type: "https_access_restricted", info: "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."}
success: false

Looks like I have to use http to call the API for free. I updated that and it works now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: there you have it: `Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption.`

Answer (score 0):

I was using https, but my subscription plan doesn't allow for that. I found this out by doing console.log(json) (as suggested by GrafiCode Studio) and it gave me the error  "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption." Updating my API url to http solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dataType to text first, and decode the json text afterwards. For example,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ip2location.io/?key=API_KEY&ip=8.8.8.8&format=json',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (text) {
        arr = $.parseJSON(text);
        console.log(arr.country_code);
    }
});
```